# How width of flex item is calculated? and how it is affected by the width of its children?

Tags: flexbox

Observation:
width of flex item increases with width of its children.

question?
I do understand flexbox to some extent but can't understand this behaviour

```
<div class="a">

<p>lorem ipsum text</p>

</div>
```

let's assume that div is a flex item already and i set width of p tag explicitly.
Now the width of div increases automatically to the same width of p tag.
But this does not happen when div is a block and not the flex item. Div takes the width of its parent and not affected by the width of its children.(when div is block rather than flex item)

Please explain this behaviour

Answer (score 0):

As you observe here `<div>` in any case takes a dynamic width according to the content placed inside it unless provided a specific dimension, also it automatically adjusts itself according to the area occupied by it's children, may it be `display:flex` or `display:block` or `inline` or `inline-flex`.
I have reproduced the same code with different classes containing different values to display attribute for better understanding.

```css
.a{
display: flex;
}
p{
width: 200px;
background-color: red;
color: white;
}

.b{
display: block;
}
.c{
display: inline
}
```

```html
<div class="a">

<p>lorem ipsum text</p>

</div>

<div class="b">

<p>lorem ipsum text</p>

</div>

<div class="c">

<p>lorem ipsum text</p>

</div>
```

Comment: No, when div is display block it takes parents width as you can see by setting its background color it occupies full width of the parent and height according to the children's content but if a div is FLEX-ITEM not display:flex , it occupies width of its children not the parent's width. That is my concern.